# Is there any difference between "they'll" and "they're going to" in this context?

Tags: difference, phrase-usage, future-tense

Is there any difference between "they'll" and "they're going to" in the context below or are they completely interchangeable?

> I made a big fool of myself at the office Christmas party, so I'm just a little nervous about how **they'll/they're going to** react when they see me again.

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: Compare https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/225345/does-the-future-will-and-be-going-to-actually-have-a-difference-between-them

Comment: There are sometimes differences over probability, timescale, and other factors. But here it's all speculative anyway (you could use "they may/might/could react" and none of it would make a significant difference).

Answer (score 0):

*As Jeff pointed out*, there is no difference whatsoever, though "be going to" would sound colloquial and would rather be used in conversational English.

Yes, they are interchangeable.

Comment: _They'll_ is colloquial too!

Comment: Yes. But not as much as "they are going to" is, right?

Comment: Contractions are always regarded as colloquial. It would be 'they will' in formal English.

Comment: [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=they+will%2C+they+are+going+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthey%20will%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthey%20are%20going%20to%3B%2Cc0) Is this graph relevant here?

Comment: Ngrams is not a reliable source. It counts errors as well

Comment: Yeah well, they are more reliable than most of the sources out there.

Answer (score -1):

There is a difference between 'They'll' and 'they're going to'.

They're going to start a business. - The decision has been made before the moment of speaking.

They'll start a business.- The decision has been made at the time of speaking.